# Autocomplete plugin for wysihtml5 editor

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete, wysihtml5

I'm looking for way to provide an autocomplete for wysihtml5 editor. I googled a little bit but found nothing. Is there a typical way to do that?

I think about jquery autocomplete  plugin but I guess it doesn't work because as I know wysihtml5 creates editable div over text area.

Comment: Can you use CKEditor for example?

Comment: Maybe. But I'm using wysihtml5 extensively in my project and I want to avoid new dependencies.

Comment: this is really a google question and not programmatic

Comment: Logically, autocomplete is a series of the following steps
1) Whatever letters entered,
2) Look from a list for similar/exact ones
3) create an element for each of them and stack them together

so can you build your own?

Comment: It's not a problem to build you own prototype. But... it's a problem to make it appropriate for every browser... it's a problem to handle all edge cases(for example: autocomplete appears somewhere on the bottom of screen)... etc. For those reason I don't want to invent a bicycle